# Get current MIDI timecode from stopped device

Tags: midi

Is there a way to ask a MIDI device for its current timecode value while it is stopped?  Specifically, I want to poll Pro Tools for its current MTC value (via the macOS Audio MIDI Setup Utility, IAC bus).  The only way I've been able to come up with is to send a play command, immediately followed by a stop command.  But I'd like to find a way to do it without moving the bus.  I've tried sending "pause", "reset", "shuttle", and "chase" commands, but nothing will get Pro Tools to send the current MTC time value besides "play."  Hoping to not have to use the old HUI protocol (if it even works with PT anymore). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MTC specification says that Full Time Code messages are sent "when equipment needs to be fast-forwarded or rewound, located or cued to a specific time". This implies that no messages are sent if the time has not changed.

So there is no standard way.